# Cycle through specific items in list retaining original index number

Tags: python, list, arraylist

I'll try to explain what I would like to accomplish with a simple example. I am looking for a solution using Python.

There is an Original List of Items:

[*0*, *1*, **2**, *3*, **4**, *5*, *6*, *7*, **8**, *9*]

Items [**2,4,8**] have a common property of **Bold**

From Original List of Items I would like to be able to cycle through only the Items which has the common property of **Bold** [**2,4,8**] skipping over the numbers in *Italic* e.g. items.type == BOLD

I know I am able to create a new list with the **Bold** items and index through those, however, I would like to be able to cycle through the Original List of Items and selecting the **Bold** items by their Original Index Number.

The reason I want to retain the Original Index Number is that when, for example, I select number **8** that I can still have access to it's previous and following numbers, *7* and *9*.

I hope that makes sense. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for pos, item in enumerate(mylist):
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use enumerate to get an iterator of tuples containing the items and their respective indexes (the tuple is actually the other way around: `(index, item)`)).

You could then use a generator-comprehension to filter out those which do not have the `type` attribute: `"BOLD"` and unpack this in a for-loop. You then have the bold items to work with, but also the indexes from the original list.

So something like:

```
for i, e in (t for t in enumerate(lst) if t[1].type == "BOLD"):
    print(e.name, 'is at index', i)
    print(lst[i-1].name, 'is before')
    print(lst[i+1].name, 'is after')
```

and when run after the following declarations:

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, type, name):
        self.type = type
        self.name = name

lst = [Item('ITALIC','Bob'), Item('BOLD','Bill'), Item('BOLD','Jim'), Item('ITALIC','Tim')]
```

we get:

```
Bill is at index 1
Bob is before
Jim is after
Jim is at index 2
Bill is before
Tim is after
```

of course, you could use an if-statement inside the loop, but I would consider this more Pythonic as you are iterating over just the bold elements.